# How to properly chain activities with new tasks?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-task

I am making alarm application. I have 3 Activities: `Main`, `Alarm`,`Game`.

They are declared in manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name=".Alarm"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        />
<activity
        android:name=".Game"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/search_word"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        />
```

`Alarm` activity is called from broadcastreciever:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Or from `Game's onBackPressed:

```
if (!test) {
     Intent i = new Intent(mContext, NotificationActivity.class);
     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(i);
}
finish();
```

`Game` activity is called from Alarm activity in similar way:

```
i = new Intent(this, BubblePopActivity.class);
i.putExtras(b);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

There is no internal calls to `Main` activity.

Behaiviour I am tring to achieve:

1) Activities `Alarm` and `Game` should be shown over lockscreen both unlocked nad locked with pin, grafical pattern and so on. It works with
flags decrared in activities, which requires FLAG_NEW_TASK in intent

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bgame);
```

2) Back button should lead from `Game` activity to `Alarm` activity
3) If `home` is pressed, while `Alarm` or `Game` activity is on top of stack, launcher icon should reopen them, but not the `Main`, as long as those activities are not finished by application logic.
While 1) and 2) works flowlesly, 3) works occasionnaly. Sometimes it returns to `Game` of `Alarm` activity as it should. It looks like if those activities were killed by system due to lack of resourses, launcher icon will lead to `Main` activity.
How can I implement desired logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added sharede preference constants. When I launch main activity, I check if alarm was dissmissed by user, then launch as normal, else launch alarm activity.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    boolean serviceIsRunning = isMyServiceRunning(AlarmService.class);
    if (serviceIsRunning) {
      boolean alarmRings = RingingAlarmUtil.getRingingAlarm(this).isExpired();
      if (!alarmRings) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    //normal launch staff
}
```